# OSX Apache running from a different directory?

Tags: macos, apache

I have apache running, but it seems to be using another directory rather than `/opt/local/apache2`:

- I have `/opt/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` setting DocumentRoot to where I want (/Users/jasons/Sites/localmirror/htdocs) but my documents aren't visible (this used to work)
- I edited /opt/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html from "It works!" to "It workkkks!" but despite restarting Apache and clearing my browser cache, it still says "It works!" when I browse http://localhost

This leads me to believe httpd is running using another directory, but I can't figure out where. Could anyone help me figure out where? `ps -ax` doesn't shed any light on anything.

---

update: found the index.html document in /Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html.en but I can't figure out why it's pointing here.

---

ARGH: I can't seem to get rid of this error:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 115 of /opt/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /opt/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: dlopen(/opt/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:\n\t/opt/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture

I have no idea where to get the right libphp5.so

Comment: That looks like you might be running a pre-installed apache instead of the one you installed in /opt (I assume via macports or similar). How are you starting apache? And can you add the output of `which httpd` to your question?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I'm running /usr/sbin/httpd for some reason, instead of the one in macports /opt/local/. I tried stopping the /usr/bin/httpd and running /opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl but it had a problem so I'm trying to reinstall w/ macports... sigh.

Answer (score 2):

Try to hit a non-existing page, then look at the error_log file. It should give you an error message along these lines:

```
[Thu Apr 12 13:06:51 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/asdasd
```

That absolute path is your document root directory.

Comment: I found the document root directory -- what I *can't* find is where the conf directory is, so I can fix the right httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you used MacPorts to install apache. Use next commands:

```
sudo port install php56 php56-apache2handler
sudo port select php php56

cd /opt/local/apache2/modules
sudo /opt/local/apache2/bin/apxs -a -e -n php5 mod_php56.so

sudo nano /opt/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
    Check that only mod_php56 is enabled, comment the rest:
        LoadModule php5_module modules/mod_php56.so
        #LoadModule php5_module modules/mod_php55.so
    and add at the end of file:
        Include conf/extra/mod_php56.conf
```

Hint:

```
sudo port install php56-exif php56-xdebug etc
```

For more info check [this link](https://gist.github.com/raphaelstolt/2721719).